# Setting custom shell with admin privileges

Tags: powershell, kiosk-mode

I am able to set an application to launch on boot-up using custom shell in Windows 10(Powershell script) to achieve Kiosk mode.

I want it to run as 'Admin', for that I disabled UAC and made it elevated in application manifest file. When I start the system a black screen pops up and the application is not visible in task manager as well(it seems application not started).

If I set it not to run as 'Admin' then it is working fine but it will not be running as elevated.

Does anybody have any idea how to launch application in admin mode using custom shell?

Thanks,
Soma

Comment: `Start-Process Application.exe -Verb runAs`?

Comment: I would like to do it by setting application as custom shell and with admin privilege.
Thanks...

Comment: If you don't want a Powershell solution why have you tagged the question with [tag:powershell]?

Comment: As OP doesn't want a code solution, voting to close as off topic and move to [su] as this is a question about Windows OS itself.

Comment: @James C,
Since I am using Powershell script to set custom shell, I tagged Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with ShellLauncher on Windows 10. The solution however is the same. Turn off User Account Control (UAC). Then, create a VBScript file with the following content, named as, say, 'launcher.vbs':

```
set shell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
cmd = "{Path to your Exe}\App.exe"
shell.run cmd,,true
```

And set the shell as "wscript.exe {path to your launcher}.vbs"